# How to detect edges of image ( coin )in android?

Tags: android, image-processing

In my application , am capturing an image of coins on table  and then immidiatley i ned to detect edges of those coins . Can any one help me how to solve this ?

regards,
Srinivas

Comment: Are you capturing single images or a live view? What do you want to do in general? Maybe there is a better way than coding it yourself.

Comment: I need to capture image (coins on table)and then i need detect edges of coins , and i need to paint border based on thier radius(1 rupee , 2 rupee , 5 rupee ) different coins and i have to count

Answer (score 1):

The're a number of [edge detecting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) , I have successfully used the Sobel edge detector before.

Comment: Can u tell me how to accomplish this task in android ? please gimme a clue . Thank u.

Comment: @bleeeah Can you please help me or suggest for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975618/how-to-detect-count-hair-from-image-using-opencv